# Meaning of "It has cost me the muscle to push back when given a direct order" from the TV Series The Man Who Fell to Earth

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am watching episode 7 (season 1) of The Man Who Fell to Earth. At some point CIA Agent Spencer, while answering questions about his conduct, says:

> "It has cost me the muscle to push back when given a direct order. Even when I know that order is wrong."

I cannot grasp what he means when he says "*it has cost me the muscle to push back*". Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please give a link (with a time stamp) of the episode? I have found [this transcript](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=1314&t=53956).

Comment: I reckon it means 'it has cost me the effort needed to resist or argue with a direct order'.

Comment: I'd guess that "muscle" means "power" or "strength", and "It has cost me" means "It has taken away". So "I no longer have the strength to resist when given a direct order."

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to the constant probation (when a person is under scrutiny to test if they are fit for the role they are fulfilling) that they are under.

To *literally* push would require muscle strength. This is a figurative use of pushing (meaning questioning the order), therefore a figurative muscle. Being under probation means that they cannot question an order, even if they know that it is wrong, because they don't have the *authority* to do so.